# How can I loop through the zone id and pass each zoneId to uosId to make an API request each

Tags: reactjs, api, loops, axios, maps

I have an endpoint that looks like below, but I need to loop through the zone and pass each zone Id to the uosid to make a request for each zone. But all zone ids are added to the URL once.
Please kindly share your idea on how I can achieve this. By passing the uos id to each zoneid, a lowest, highest and average price is shown which is displayed to the user

```
import "./styles.css";
import Axios from "axios"
import { useState } from "react";

const zone =[
 {
   "id":"08edusow839",
   "zonename":"Lagos",
   "area":"lag"
 },
 {
   "id":"672gud78292",
   "zonename":"Surulere",
   "area":"lere"
 },
 {
   "id":"829hdia90ww",
   "zonename":"Mainland",
   "area":"main"
 },
 {
   "id":"9oe92hi8q99",
   "zonename":"Island",
   "area":"land"
 },
 {
   "id":"172eqikeo83",
   "zonename":"Yaba",
   "area":"Aba"
 },
]

 const uos =[
  {
   "id":'36727hdjd',
   "uosname":"name"
  }
 ]

 const zoneId = zone.map(zoe =>zoe.id)

 export default function App() {

 const [price, setPrice] = useState("")

 return (
    <div className="App">
    <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
  {uos.map(us=>{
  <button
    onClick={
      async () => {
        try {
          const response = await `https:wearehere.come/${zoneId}/${us.id}`
          setPrice(response.data)
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err)
        }
    }
    }
  > Fetch Price</button>
  })}

  {price?.map(single =>{
    return(
      <div>
          name:Lagos
          <p>  {single.lowest} </p>
          <p> {single.highest}</p>
          <p> {single.average}</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          name:Surulere
          <p>  {single.lowest} </p>
          <p> {single.highest}</p>
          <p> {single.average}</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          name:Mainland
          <p>  {single.lowest} </p>
          <p> {single.highest}</p>
          <p> {single.average}</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          name:Island
          <p>  {single.lowest} </p>
          <p> {single.highest}</p>
          <p> {single.average}</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          name:Yaba
          <p>  {single.lowest} </p>
          <p> {single.highest}</p>
          <p> {single.average}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  })}

</div>
);
}
```

Comment: Try to clarify your question or show an example of what you want to achieve exactly (what should be the final link) as I can't make sure what's your goal.

Comment: I am trying to see how I can loop through the zone to get the zoneId for each zone and pass the uosid and call the onclick function. Each one with the uosid passed to `https:wearehere.come/${zoneId}/${us.id}` is expected to return price

Comment: how you define which zoneId yo uwant to have ? what's the criteria to choose a zone ?

Comment: I am not choosing a particular zone, I am just trying to display the price under each zone by adding the uosid to the id to each one of the zone through the URL endpoint

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem, seems you want to loop on the zones rather than on the uos:

```
  {zone.map(oneZone=>{
     return <button
       onClick={
         async () => {
           try {
             const response = await `https:wearehere.come/${oneZone.id}/${uos.id}`
             setPrice(response.data)
           } catch (err) {
             console.log(err)
           }
         }
       }
  > Fetch Price</button>
  })}
```